# How to handle deeply nested exception in struts2?

Tags: exception, struts2

My struts2 webapp makes use of a SQL database.  Within the DB access code, I've written a basic try/catch handler that catches SQL or general exceptions, writes the detail to a log file, and then continues.  The hierarchy of classes is as follows:

Action method -> get or set method on Model -> DB access.

```
//Action method in action class
public string doActionMethod() throws Exception
{
    String results = SampleModel.getResults();
}

//Model method in model class
public string getResults() throws Exception
{
    String results = DBLayer.runQuery("SELECT Results FROM SampleTable WHERE Value='1');
}

//Method that queries database in DB access class
public string runQuery() throws Exception
{
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;     

    dbConnection = MSSQLConnection.getConnection();

    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);

    //run SQL statements

    return String(rs.get(0));
}
```

I'd like caught exceptions to bubble up to the Action level, so that I can forward them to an appropriate error page.  Is there a better way to do this than adding a "throws Exception" to the method signature?

Comment: have your forgotten the parameter `sqlQuery` for your method `runQuery()`

Comment: can't you do `if(results == whatYouWant) then return SUCCESS, else show some error message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no hope of recovery, throw an application-specific `RuntimeException`.

Use standard Struts 2 declarative exception handling to get your app to the appropriate error page.